# Pipe to command that does not accept piping

Tags: linux, bash

I want to use MPC (CLI interface to MPD) but unfortunately to me it does not accept piping.

So something like:

```
ll | grep "pattern" | sed 's/this/that/' | mpc
```

does not work for me, nor

```
ll | grep "pattern" | sed 's/this/that/' | mpc -
```

This

```
MPCTMP=`ll | grep "pattern" | sed 's/this/that/'` && echo $MPCTMP
```

works as expected, but this:

```
MPCTMP=`ll | grep "pattern" | sed 's/this/that/'` && mpc $MPCTMP
```

does not return results, variable is not understood but this program

I'm new to Linux and could not find anything searching with Google

Thanks

Comment: So, how does it want it's input then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs)

```
ll | grep "pattern" | sed 's/this/that/' | xargs mpc
```